# javascript extract object array to variables like php, c# extract object array to variables like php

Tags: javascript, c#, php

PHP **extract**() function uses array keys as variable names and values as variable values. For each element it will create a variable in the current symbol table.
Do we have the same function in C# or JavaScript?

PHP Example, Assign the values "Cat", "Dog" and "Horse" to the variables $a, $b and $c:

```
<?php
    $a = "Original";
    $my_array = array("a" => "Cat","b" => "Dog", "c" => "Horse");
    extract($my_array);
    echo "\$a = $a; \$b = $b; \$c = $c";
?> 
Output is: $a = Cat; $b = Dog; $c = Horse
```

Comment: There's no way to do this in C#.

Comment: I think it'll help you: https://github.com/jimbojw/php-extract.js/blob/master/extract.js

Comment: Does C# support variable names as variables? If it does, you can just loop through an array and create such variables manually.

Comment: @MaxShaian If you look at it this way, you can do it in many other ways, but it's not suitable for clean code

Comment: @mirzaei.sajad I always thought that php extract() function does exactly such a thing under the hood.
But I have gotten your point. You wanted to do it as clean as php allows to do. Basically, that's what this function exist for. I use helpers functions for such cases, where I determine my own convenient functions and use them throughout my application.

Comment: @MaxShaian Like you, I get help from the functions that I write myself, but before I do, I ask and search for a better solution.
Anyway, thank you and everyone else for answering

Answer (score 1):

The nearest I found is called "destructuring"

```
var arr = {"a":"Cat", "b":"Dog", "c":"Horse"}
var {a, b, c} = arr
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function simliar to php's extract:

```js
function extract(dict, dest=globalThis) {
    for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(dict))
        dest[k] = v;
}
let dict = {a: "Cat", b: "Dog", c: "Horse"}; 

extract(dict);
// if you have custom global: extract(dict, dest="global"), extract(dict, dest="window") etc.

console.log(a === "Cat");
console.log(b === "Dog");
console.log(c === "Horse");
```

`Object.entries` converts `dict` to `Array`, and then iterate through it. Setting `globalThis` (or global object) with key and value of the `dict`.

---

Or you could do the same thing using the `...` spread operator:

```js
globalThis = {...globalThis, ...dict};
```